# warpProspective co-ordinated

Tags: c, opencv, homography, homogenous-transformation

I am transforming image2 with respect to image1 using 'warpperspective' function of opencv.

the ourput image is as below. Can anybody tell me how I can know the co-ordinate corner pointed below in the image?

the code for warprospective is as follows -

```
 std::vector< Point2f > points1,points2;
    for( int i = 0; i < matches1.size(); i++ )
       {
        points1.push_back( keypoints_input1[matches1[i].queryIdx ].pt );
        points2.push_back( keypoints_input2[matches1[i].trainIdx ].pt );
       }
    /* Find the Homography Matrix for current and next frame*/
     Mat H1 = findHomography( points2, points1, CV_RANSAC );
     /* Use the Homography Matrix to warp the images*/
    cv::Mat result1;
    warpPerspective(input2, result1, H1, Size(input2.cols+150, input2.rows+150),              
INTER_CUBIC);
imshow("resut",result1);


...
}
```

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the coordinates of the corners of the warped image, you can do the following:

```
cv::Mat_<float> p(3,1), c_topleft, c_topright, c_botleft, c_botright;

p(0)=0; p(1)=0; p(2)=1;
c_topleft=H1*p; c_topleft/=c_topleft(2); // Top-Left corner

p(0)=input2.cols-1; p(1)=0; p(2)=1;
c_topright=H1*p; c_topright/=c_topright(2); // Top-right corner

p(0)=0; p(1)=input2.rows-1; p(2)=1;
c_botleft=H1*p; c_botleft/=c_botleft(2); // Bottom-left corner

p(0)=input2.cols-1; p(1)=input2.rows-1; p(2)=1;
c_botright=H1*p; c_botright/=c_botright(2); // Bottom-right corner
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but every corner should have 2 values right? like c_topleft(x,y)? I am sorry but, I am little confuse, and what does c_topleft/=c_topleft(2) means?

Comment: Yes, each corner is a 3x1 vector, so for instance you can access the x value by doing `c_topleft(0)` and the y value by doing `c_topleft(1)`. The division is needed when using homographies, in order to convert the _homogeneous_ point representation to _classic_ point coordinates. Basically, after transforming a point using a homography, always scale the third vector element to 1 to obtain pixel coordinates.

Comment: ok, I understand, so do I need to declare cv::Mat c_topleft(3,1) , same as P(3,1) ? let me try your code. hope it will work.

Comment: Not necessarily because it will be properly allocated by the matrix-vector multiplication operation.

Comment: sorry but p(1)=0; p(2)=1; doesnot work and neither c_topright(2);

Comment: @MMH I'm sorry, coding without testing is no good ;) The new edit should work now.

Comment: thanks for your kind responses I really appreciate it. The code currently doesn't have any error. but when I print the co-ordinate, the value doesn't look proper  c_topleft(0.094393,0.003038), c_topright(0.094303,0.003038),c_botlet(0.094303,0.003038) I am print as float values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48662/discussion-between-aldurdisciple-and-mmh)

Comment: hi Aldur, please check this question . may be you can help me again -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472871/calculating-new-positions-of-keypoints