# Calculating new positions of keypoints

Tags: c++, c, opencv, homography, warp

can somebody help me, how we can calculate the new positions of  keypoints in the transformed image,the keypoints were detected in original image.  I am using opencv homography matrix and  warpPerspective to make the transformed image.

Here is a code..

```
...
 std::vector< Point2f > points1,points2;
 for( int i = 0; i < matches1.size(); i++ )
    {
     points1.push_back( keypoints_input1[matches1[i].queryIdx ].pt );
     points2.push_back( keypoints_input2[matches1[i].trainIdx ].pt );
    }
 /* Find the Homography Matrix for current and next frame*/
 Mat H1 = findHomography( points2, points1, CV_RANSAC );
 /* Use the Homography Matrix to warp the images*/
cv::Mat result1;
warpPerspective(input2, result1, H1, Size(input2.cols+150, input2.rows+150),              
INTER_CUBIC);
...
}
```

Now I want to calculate the new positions of points2 in the result1 image.

For example in the below transformed image[image] , we know the corner points. Now I want to calculate the new position of the keypoints say before transformation {(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)...}, How we can calculate it?

Update: opencv 'perspectiveTransform' does what I trying to do.

Comment: this is a question about mathematics and transformations; not about programming...

Comment: @Chris Maes,  computer-vision is about programming mathematic transformations

Comment: ok you have a point, my comment was maybe not clear enough. but this question is clearly a "how to do my math" question and not a programmatic question, no?

Comment: @ChrisMaes , Thanks for your comment, I really don't know, how to do it that is why I am asking. I don't think anything is wrong in asking people who knows about it.

Comment: @MMH I didn't want to be rude. I understand your question but you'd better paste 5 lines of code on how you wrap your image and where exactly you are stuck; that is a lots easier to answer... my opinion maybe

Comment: @ChrisMaes, I have updated my questions, hope it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call `I'` the image obtained by warping image `I` using homography `H`.

If you extracted keypoints **m<sub>i</sub>** = (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>, 1) in original image `I`, you can get the keypoints **m'<sub>i</sub>** in the warped image `I'` using the homography transform: S * **m'<sub>i</sub>** = H * **m<sub>i</sub>**. Notice the scale factor S, if you want the keypoints coordinates in pixels, you *have* to scale **m'<sub>i</sub>** so that the third element is 1.

If you want to understand where the scale factor comes from, have a look at [Homogeneous Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).

Also, there is an OpenCV function to apply this transformation to an array of points: `perspectiveTransform`([documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform)).

Comment: Hi Aldur thanks, the keypoints are extracted in I, not in I', I want to recalculate it in I'. I think it can be calculated same way. thanks

Comment: @MMH I updated my answer. Though, your question states that you want keypoint coordinates _before_ transformation... Try to describe your problem more clearly next time ;)

Comment: @MMH OK, I updated my answer to mention the OpenCV function `perspectiveTransform`, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, perspectiveTransform works perfectly, what I was looking for. thank you.

Comment: @AldurDisciple that answer is exactly what I am looking for. Is there anywhere I could go to see an example? I think I understand the math but putting it to practice is a little much for me.

Comment: can this perspective transform be done directly to keypoints of type vector<keypoint> or do they need to be localized to vector<point2f>?

Comment: @C.Radford vector<keypoint> won't work, you need to use vector<point2f> or vector<point2d>.

Comment: @Awesome thanks. Do you know if there is a way to return the localized keypoints  "vector<point2f>" back to vector<keypoint>

Comment: @AldurDisciple follow-ip question: Can the same process of  find their new location be done to the descriptors of those keypoints or is that not necessary?